# Converting string to float and formatting it (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am attempting to convert a float into a string.

I have a string (dividedstring[2]) that represents CPU load e.g. 0.00 or 0.01 or 0.54 etc.

I then would like to convert this into a float, so I do the following:

```
float.TryParse(dividedstring[2], out insertCPUvalue);
```

Now when I attempt to display the float e.g.:

```
MessageBox.Show(insertCPUvalue.ToString());
```

I get: "0", now I am assuming this is because the string "dividedstring[2]" was == "0.00", so it has just taken the decimal points of? - and rounded it to 0?

Comment: Is dividedstring a string Array?

Comment: Maybe it is because of the cultural settings what is your decimal point there is it a "," or a "." that could mess with the parser.

Comment: You should specify a culture when parsing(probably you want `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`). Also you need to either use `Parse` or check the return value of `TryParse`.

Comment: Added an answer where you use an InvariantCulture to parse the string and as @CodeInChaos wrote you should check the return value too because if you get false then parsing failed and you get the float default value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float f = 0.0000666f;
Messagebox.Show(String.Format("{0:0,0.0000000}", f));
```

Answer (score 5):

If `insertCPUvalue` is `float`, you can use

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0:0.00}%", insertCPUvalue));
```

More on formats:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
MessageBox.Show(insertCPUvalue.ToString("0.00"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use invariant culture to parse your string like this.

```
float.TryParse("0.58", NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out f);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
MessageBox.Show(insertCPUvalue.ToString("F02"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you have 2 elements in `dividedstring` (array of 2 elements), and you are passing `dividedstring[2]` which is nothing (since the index starts from `0`, so you have element `0` and element `1`), this will throw an exception but `TryParse` will catch it and return assign `0`, so try passing `dividedstring[1]` istead.

To make sure of that, just try using Parse:

```
insertCPUvalue.Parse(dividedstring[2]);
```

If my prediction is correct, this should throw an exception.